# Minikube HOME folder

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I'm try to run Kubernetes with minikube, and hangs on creating volume...
My HOME partition is almost 100% used. 
I saw that minikube create a .minikube folder into my HOME, so there are way to change this folder?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set the MINIKUBE_HOME env var to specify the path for minikube to use for the .minikube directory.  From:
<strike>https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/docs/env_vars.md</strike>

EDIT: information has moved, now at - https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/config

Comment: This answer is still correct, added this comment because the link is broken. The env variables can be found here: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/config/ .

Comment: windows `cmd` need restart after set MINIKUBE_HOME then the env var update